# What is the difference between "metaphorically speaking" and "so to speak"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is there any difference between the following two sentences?

1. "He is a parrot, so to speak."
2. "He is a parrot, metaphorically speaking."

Comment: They are similar, but 'so to speak' is very general. He locked the door in my face, so to speak (when he actually slammed it without locking it).  Would you say he locked it metaphorically?

Comment: Sure. Meta-metaphor (which is what this is, unfortunately) is spontaneous, rare, and of no lasting importance -- it just points at the metaphor, which is the important thing.

Answer (score 1):

"So to speak" can imply a more personal expression - refering to a common knowledge.  It does not infer that the opinion of the one stating it has considered the meaning in a formal sense; as though it is classified into a group of pre-determined social or grammatical contexts.
"Metaphorically speaking" implys a relation to a group, class of analogies.  This could represent a formal level of association in meanings.  If I say this I may be infering that I possess the capacity to classify the meaning in a formal sense.